# How do I make the text in last row bold in a table using @foreach?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to make the text in the last row bold using `@foreach` html?

I want to display the total sum of each column in in bold text.
I thought about making a new table below the current one, only displaying the total, but if I can use the same table it would be great.

**Model**

```
//This is the last row
foreach (DataRow item in current2.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var cid2 = new SModel
    {
        Users = Convert.ToInt32(item["TotalUsers"]),
        Rows = Convert.ToInt32(item["TotalRows"]),
        Orders = Convert.ToInt32(item["TotalOrders"]),
        Customers = Convert.ToInt32(item["TotalCustomers"]),
        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(item["TotalQuantity"]),
    };

    CASVList.Add(cid2);
}
```

**View**

```asp
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Hour</th>
        <th>Users</th>
        <th>Customers</th>
        <th>Orders</th>
        <th>Rows</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.SModelObject.CSItem)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Text.Split(',')[0]))</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Text.Split(',')[1]))</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Text.Split(',')[2]))</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Text.Split(',')[3]))</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Text.Split(',')[4]))</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Text.Split(',')[5]))</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use css :last-child?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just give the last row a CSS selector that gives bold to all its' children:

```
tr:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Aaa was it that easy.. Thanks! @Narxx

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you're looking for something like this:

```css
table tr:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You can do this easily by using **CSS**

```
table tr:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;  
}
```

---

**2)**

Else if you are particular about only doing it in the foreach loop then the below code will help.

```
{ var countOfItems = Model.SModelObject.CSItem.Count;  //take a note of total items 
  var loopCounter = 1;                                 // have a counter
}

@foreach (var item in Model.SModelObject.CSItem)
        {
            //if counter and the total items count are same it means you are in last loop,
            // So add the style to make the text bold.
            <tr style="@{loopCounter == countOfItems ? "font-weight: bold":"" }">
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Text.Split(',')[0]))</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Text.Split(',')[1]))</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Text.Split(',')[2]))</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Text.Split(',')[3]))</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Text.Split(',')[4]))</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Text.Split(',')[5]))</td>
            </tr>
          loopCounter+;
        }
```

---